# Turn.js Disable Event Handling of Page Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, turnjs

I am using turn.js to make a flip book. Everything is fine, but when I try to bind an event to an element inside a page, the event isn't bound.

```javascript
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $("#Test").click(function(e) {
     alert('some text')
   });
   $("#book").turn("page",$("#book").turn("pages"));
 });
```

```html
<p>
  <div id="book" >
    <div class="even">
      <div class="data">1</div>
    </div>  
    <div class="odd">
      <div class="data">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="even">
      <div class="data"><span id="Test">3</span></div>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

jQuery doesn't bind any event to `#Test`.

Comment: I think turn.js removes bound handler, just try by setting click handler after `.turn()` and see if that's making any difference. Or check in your console: `$._data($("#Test")[0],"events").click` If click handler is there, something worst happen

Comment: working for me, check http://jsfiddle.net/pranavq212/9C2Jr/

Comment: @PranavSingh what is working? You don't include turn.js in your jsfiddle at all

Comment: Alert "some text" on clicking 3

Comment: Ya but what happen if you include turn.js???

Comment: @A.Wolff I am unable to find any link for hosted turn.js, its source is on github but home website says it needs licence http://www.turnjs.com/get :(

Comment: @PranavSingh , You Haven't included turn.js in your sample , if you include it doesn't work , turn.js version 3 is free but version 4 is licence d , i am using version 3

Comment: maybe this can help, the syntax for events is a bit different => http://turnjs.com/docs/Turn_Events